# Trazer valor DropDownList ASP.NET MV5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Estou trazendo uma `dropdown` de uma tabela de Médicos na `View` e ela traz normalmente, porém quero pegar o valor dela (*Nome selecionado*) no `jQuery` para trazer demais informações após selecionado.

Porém sempre que seleciono o item e pego pelo `jQuery`, ele traz o valor do primeiro nome da lista e não o nome da pessoa selecionada.

Como devo proceder?

Controler:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.MedicoId = new SelectList(db.Medicos, "Id", "Nome");
    ViewBag.PacienteId = new SelectList(db.Pacientes, "Id", "Nome");
    return View();
}
```

View para recuperar os dados:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MedicoId, "Nome Médico:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("MedicoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MedicoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

`jQuery` que pega o valor selecionado na `dropdown` (*este que esta com problema, só traz o primeiro nome da lista, independente que eu mude*)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var c = $("#MedicoId option:selected").val();
    $("#MedicoId").change(function () {
        console.log(c);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que pegar o valor pelo evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) da seguinte forma:

```js
function setMedicoValueDiv(value) {
  $("#medico-id-value").text(value);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setMedicoValueDiv($("#MedicoId").val());
  $("#MedicoId").change(function() {
    setMedicoValueDiv($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MedicoId" name="MedicoId">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
<span id="medico-id-value"></span>
```

ou seja, você está fazendo errado.